# error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 (for lssl and lcrypto)

Tags: python, gcc

I've tried installing whatever was suggested, `libssl-dev` being the most common answer, but I still receive the error:

```
PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyInt_FromString(char*, char**, int);
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
   ----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cujwKQ/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cujwKQ/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-dlLRwV/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
 WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3.1; however, version 20.0.2 is available.
 You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: libssl.so, libcrypto.so not found : Install libssl → `sudo apt install libssl-dev`

Answer (score 12):

Try `sudo apt-get install python3.X-dev` where X is your python3 subversion.

Comment: Please explain **why** you think that this command should help solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev portaudio19-dev libssl-dev python3-dev
```

Comment: This doesn't really add anything new.

Answer (score 0):

Might be libssl:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Also try this:

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Install these packages:

```bash
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev libssl-dev
```